# AZ CLI Query Resources with Dashes in name

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-cli

I am trying to check if a subscription rule exists before attempting to create the rule but I am getting an error suggesting (I am assuming it doesn't like the dashes in the name).

How do I query something with dashes in its name?

```
ERROR: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: '[?name==foo-bar-hello-world]'
```

The powershell script I am using is this

```
$existingRule = az servicebus topic subscription list `
-g 'my-rg' `
--namespace-name 'some-namespace' `
--topic-name 'my-topic' `
--query "[?name==$SubscriptionName]" `
| ConvertFrom-Json
```

This is called from a yml pipeline file

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Add Topic Rule'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{parameters.azureResourceManagerConnection}}'
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
      scriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/Scripts/Create-TopicRule.ps1'
      ScriptArguments: >-
        -subscriptionName 'foo-bar-hello-world'
```

Comment: COuld you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: The command `az servicebus topic subscription list` just can be used to list subscriptions in one topic.

Comment: Hi @DrSchizo, How are things going? Have you tried as the suggestion in my answer? Is  it helpful to you? Please have a try, and any update, feel free to tell us.

Answer (score 1):

The query language is JMESPath. According to my tests in the [**JMESPath Tutorial**](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#filter-projections), if the specified value is a string in the query, it should be surrounded by the single quotation.

- Have single quotation surround the value in the query, can return the correct result.

[image]

- No single quotation surround the value in the query, return empty.

[image]

In your case, you can try to change the PowerShell script like as below to see if it can work.

```
$existingRule = az servicebus topic subscription list `
-g 'my-rg' `
--namespace-name 'some-namespace' `
--topic-name 'my-topic' `
--query "[?name=='$SubscriptionName']" `
| ConvertFrom-Json
```